# Reload ListView When Going Back to Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

My app has a main activity that is a FragmentActivity with a TabHost. The first tab has a fragment with a list view that is populated with objects from Parse. When an item is selected from the list, a new activity is loaded with the details for that item and the user can mark the item as completed. When they return to the list view by hitting the back button, I want the data to be reloaded. How can I do that?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Unassigned").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unassigned)), UnassignedJobsFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Assigned").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.assigned)), AssignedJobsFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Completed").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.completed)), CompletedJobsFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("My Jobs").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myjobs)), MyJobsFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Users").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.users)), Users.class, null);
    }
}
```

List Fragment:

```
public class UnassignedJobsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageButton mAddJobButton;
    ProgressBar mUnassignedProgress;
    ListView listView;
    List<ParseObject> object;
    List<String> objectIds;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unassigned, container, false);
        mAddJobButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.addJobButton);
        mUnassignedProgress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.unassignedProgress);
        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.unassignedList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.job_list_item);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ParseObject selectedObject = object.get(position);
                String objectId = objectIds.get(position);
                String jobTitle = selectedObject.getString("job");
                String worker = selectedObject.getString("worker");
                String details = selectedObject.getString("details");

                Date jobDate = selectedObject.getDate("date");
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
                String dateString = dateFormat.format(jobDate);

                Boolean accessedFromMyJobs = false;

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("OBJECT_ID", objectId);
                intent.putExtra("JOB_TITLE", jobTitle);
                intent.putExtra("WORKER", worker);
                intent.putExtra("DETAILS", details);
                intent.putExtra("DATE", dateString);
                intent.putExtra("FROM_MY_JOBS", accessedFromMyJobs);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        String fullName = currentUser.get("Name").toString();
        if (fullName.equals("Cory Pollard") || fullName.equals("Richie Ray")) {
            mAddJobButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            mAddJobButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        getJobs();

        return v;
    }

    public void getJobs() {
        mUnassignedProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Jobs");
        query.setLimit(1000);
        query.whereEqualTo("assigned", "no");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    object = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
                    objectIds = new ArrayList<String>();

                    mUnassignedProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    for (ParseObject job : parseObjects) {
                        object.add(job);
                        objectIds.add(job.getObjectId().toString());
                    }

                    for (ParseObject job : object) {
                        adapter.add((String) job.getString("job"));
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    mUnassignedProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    String exception = e.getMessage().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Populate the listview in your onResume method of your fragment

Comment: I added onResume() and call my getJobs() method in it instead of in onCreateView(). It reloads the list but it duplicates each item when I press the back button from the detail activity.

Comment: ok did you figure out how to remove the duplicates or you still having the issue

Comment: I got the duplicate issue resolved. Everything is working like it should with my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

implement the onSaveInstanceState and save any or all objects that need to be restored, then you can get those objects back in your oncreate, in your case it is oncreateview.

this is an example on how it is done,

```
@Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) 
  {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putStringArrayList("My List" , listArray);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  if(savedInstanceState!=null)
  {
    listArray = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("My List");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using onResume() as suggested by @krishna. I set the adapter here instead of in onCreate().

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        object = null;
        objectIds = null;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.job_list_item);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        getJobs();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is the best implementation.

In 2nd Activity

```
//after entry has been successfully made 
SharedPreferences sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()):
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SharedPreferences. edit();
editor. putBoolean("refresh_fragment_listview", true); 
editor. commit();
```

In Fragment

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()):
    String refreshValue sharedpref.getBoolean("refresh_fragment_listview", false) :
    if (refreshValue.equals("true") {
        //reset the value to false to prevent refresh each time
        //fragment is resumed
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SharedPreferences. edit();
        editor. putBoolean("refresh_fragment_listview", true); 
        editor. commit();

        //add methods to refresh the listview below
    }
}
```